# PHP - Grouping another element into antoher element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I have a lot of data from database.

Now, This data will be displaying to another array format in programming level.

Sometimes, I am grouping column in database level.
But now, in programming level, How to grouping another element into another element in an array.

I use PHP. Here is the data (Array)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 01
            [date_start_booking] => 2017-07-24 11:00:00
            [bookings] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 01
            [date_start_booking] => 2017-07-24 08:00:00
            [bookings] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 01
            [date_start_booking] => 2017-07-24 12:00:00
            [bookings] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 02
            [date_start_booking] => 2017-07-24 08:00:00
            [bookings] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I need an array that like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 01
            [date_start_booking] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2017-07-24 11:00:00
                    [1] => 2017-07-24 08:00:00
                    [2] => 2017-07-24 12:00:00
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [kode_lapangan] => 02
            [date_start_booking] => 
                (
                    [0] => 2017-07-24 08:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a step back and see if you can let your database do most of the work.

You can easily group your results in sql like so:

SELECT kode_lapangan, GROUP_CONCAT(date_start_booking) as dates FROM booking GROUP BY kode_lapangan;

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

I'm assuming mysql here for a minute, but this will work in most database engines.

This will make an array in the form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [kode_lapangan] => 01
        [dates] => "2017-07-24 11:00:00,2017-07-24 08:00:00,2017-07-24 12:00:00"
            )

    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [kode_lapangan] => 02
        [dates] => "2017-07-24 08:00:00"
    )
)
```

But if that is not an option... You can always rebuild the array as Alive to die mentioned